# How can I block factory reset on a phone?

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset, frp

is there a way to block factory reset on a phone? Like delete the functionality, make it totally impossible. Thanks!

Note: Not something like Factory Reset Protection, something that doesn't let you wipe the phone in the first place.

Comment: To deter a  third party from doing factory reset you'd need to do three things: (1) setup protected lock screen so that factory reset cannot be done using Settings app unless your lock screen credentials are known to the party; Additionally, use 2FA on Google account or remove Google account from your device, or at least disable Google Play Services (2) modify kernel image and remove the part which loads recovery or modify it so that so it become non-trivial to do anything with it...

Comment: ...(3) disable access to low-level interfaces that can factory reset your device -- this is a bit hard. How to disable access to fastboot mode or the mode that is used to flash MTK device? 3. is most problematic to do with no surety at the end.

Comment: @Firelord I want to make it that it can't be reset from the settings app.